# react app + spring cloud gateway (BFF) + spring authorization server (oauth2 server) cors issue

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, spring-authorization-server

i have a react app running on localhost:3000 and call api from spring cloud gateway running on localhost:8060

the gateway act as oauth2 client

the spring authorization server running on localhost:8000

when call an api from react it get cors error

whats my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to serve both the REST API and the React app through the gateway: from the browser point of view, all requests would have the same origin (the gateway) which removes the need for any CORS configuration.

Gateway configuration will have at least two routes. Something like:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      routes:
      - id: api
        uri: http://localhost:8000
        predicates:
        - Path=/api/**
        filters:
        - SaveSession
        - TokenRelay=
        - StripPrefix=1
      - id: ui
        uri: http://localhost:3000
        predicates:
        - Path=/ui/**
```

You then point your browser to `http://localhost:8060/ui`. Of course, this also requires to configure the React app with `/ui` as `basePath` and to prefix requests to API with `/api`.

You may also add `/ui/**` to the list of `permitAll` path matchers (you probably want users to load the React app before they are authenticated).

I have a written a complete tutorial for Baeldung [there](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).

Comment: thanks alot for your answer 

this solve my issue but when my browser call http://localhost:8060/ui 

nothing happen 

in network tab i can see some 302 (redirect) for authorization_code_flow and /login 

but dont redirect me to /login

Comment: You might have misconfigured the Spring Security OAuth2 client stuf in the Gateway, but as you already figured out, this is a completely different question (with an answer in the tutorials I linked).

Comment: hi, @ch4mp; not related to this question but with the same setup how user roles and authorities are passed to and accessed from the UI?

Comment: In [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2), I do it with a resource server `/me` endpoint reflecting some data from the access token. Note that the version I wrote for Baeldung now has a sample frontend with React (in addition to Angular and Vue ones)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is valid, but you might also consider using an nginx reverse proxy that will redirect all requests coming from the browser to your BFF server. So from browser's position it looks like all XHRs and your static files are served from the same origin, and thus it will not yield a CORS error!

The benefits are that:

1. Your React app and BFF can be deployed and released separately
2. Nginx is fairly easy to configure and deploy + it is a powerful tool if you want to customize it and secure your backend.

Cons:

1. Maintaining a reverse proxy is a bit an extra work to do but really once you configured chances are you don't to change ever.
2. When you develop locally on your machine (running react on localhost and BFF on remote server, you still have to run a local nginx config)